# Inno-setup - add registry when two components are checked

Tags: inno-setup

How do i add a registry entry only in case the two of components are selected? I tried 
Components: A and B, but I got an error that "and" is a non-existing component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works fine in my Version 5.5.1:

```
[Components]  
Name: "a"; Description: "Description A"  
Name: "b"; Description: "Description B"  

[Registry]  
Root: "HKCU"; Subkey: "a Subkey"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "Some Value"; Components: a and b
```

Comment: Support for expressions wer only added a year or so back so make sure you have a recent version.

Answer (score 0):

Try ".......; Components: a b"

Comment: The individual components are evaluated as an OR expression, not an AND.